# call event from ajax call result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a function from the ajax result i get. also need to pass the abstract id from the ajax success result. Can you please let me know how to do it.

from the below code, i need to dynamically create a href from the success result and then using the abstract id they click, i need to call the 2nd method.

1st ajax call --

```
 $('.select-categories').click(function () {
        var categorynames = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("..", "Home")',
            data: { .... },
            success: function (data) {
                var json_length = data.length;
                var row = "<a href='#' id='selectcategoriesback' class='select-categories-Back'>Back</a><br/>";
                for (var i = 0; i < json_length - 1; i++)
                {
                    row += "<tr><td>" +  "<br/>" +
                        "<a href='#' data-id='" + data[i].AbstractID + "' id='CategorySelect_(" + data[i].AbstractID + ")' class='select-abstracts'>" + "Abstract #" +
                        data[i].AbstractID + "</a>" + "<br/>" + "</td></tr>";
                };
                $("#onfilterloadvalues").html(row);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

2nd Ajax Call --

```
$('.select-abstracts').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var abstractids = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetIndividualAbstracts", "Home")',
            data: { abstractid: abstractids },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                ....
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your elements with `class="select-abstracts"` are be being added after the DOM has been loaded. You need to use event delegation - `$(document).on('click', '.select-abstracts', function() { ....` (replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first loaded)

Answer (score 0):

just use the onclick attribute of the elements - this should work

```
 row += "<tr><td>" +  "<br/>" +
                    "<a href='#' data-id='" + data[i].AbstractID + "' id='CategorySelect_(" + data[i].AbstractID + ")' onclick='yourmethod(this)' class='select-abstracts'>" + "Abstract #" +
                    data[i].AbstractID + "</a>" + "<br/>" + "</td></tr>";


function yourmethod(elem) {
    debugger;
    var abstractids = $(elem).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetIndividualAbstracts", "Home")',
        data: { abstractid: abstractids },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            ....
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
};
```